# How to implement async api in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

Maybe this was asked hundreds of times but: on my website i want to be able to add/update/verify/remove/check if user exists and do it **asynchronously**, so this is how it is implemented:

```
public class UserRepo 
 {
    public async Task<bool> Add(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (await Exists(model.UserName)) return false;

            using (var db = new DataConnection(provider, Context))
            {
                var users = db.GetTable<User>();

                db.Insert(new User()
                {
                    Username = model.UserName,
                    Password = model.Password
                });
            }

            return await Exists(model.UserName);
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> Remove(int id)
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var db = new DataConnection(provider, Context))
            {
                var users = db.GetTable<User>();

                users.Where(x => x.Id == id).Delete();
                return users.Any(x => x.Id == id);
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task Update(User user)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (!(await Exists(user.Username))) return;

            using (var db = new DataConnection(provider, Context))
            {
                db.Update(user);
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> Verify(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var db = new DataConnection(provider, Context))
            {
                return db.GetTable<User>().Any(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == model.Password);
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<bool> Exists(string username)
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var db = new DataConnection(provider, Context))
            {
                return db.GetTable<User>().Any(x => x.Username == username);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Though it works, honestly i still have a feeling that it's implemented badly, and here is my question - is there a better way to implement async api?

Comment: I don't necessarily understand why you're wrapping everything in `Task.Run()`.  The await-able calls are being awaited, the synchronous calls are synchronous, what specifically are you trying to achieve when you say "do it asynchronously"?

Comment: Well, things like searching through database are completely synchronous, but i want to make them asynchronous, so i wrap them in `Task.Run()`. But honestly, this topic with tasks is a bit complicated to me, i don't understand where, when and how i should use task/ async tasks

Comment: @iterstar: You didn't answer *why*. *Why* do you want them to be asynchronous?

Comment: You seem to be using some ORM. Is it [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)? It's important to know, because `async` in ASP.NET makes sense only when the underlying operation is actually asynchronous.